# Perl WWW:Mechanize/HTML:TokeParser and following/storing URL from href attr

Tags: perl, web-scraping, perl-module, www-mechanize

i am making some good progress with Perl due to the help on this site but i've run into a problem. One of the pages i was scraping from has changed and i can't figure out how to get to it now. What i want to do is store a link to each page i want to get to. The problem is that these links are inside the a href attribute tags in the source code and i have no idea how to extract them. Could anyone help me?

the links i need are from line 316 to 354 of this page(source code) http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/home.sd

i need to basically extract the links to variables for use in my other scripts. As mentioned i am using WWW::Mechanize and HTML::TokeParser, hopefully there are methods within these that i can use but can't currently figure out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [method `find_all_links` in WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-find_all_links-...-). No need to bother manually with the parser. You probably want to relax the regex so that you get all ~1000 possible teams at once.

```
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
my $w = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$w->get('http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/home.sd');
for my $link ($w->find_all_links(url_regex => qr/comp_id=1\b/)) {
    # 20 instances of WWW::Mechanize::Link
    printf "URL=%s\tTeam=%s\n", $link->url_abs, $link->text
}
```

---

```
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/tournaments/tournament.sd?comp_id=1       Team=Premier League
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=142&comp_id=1       Team=Arsenal
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=154&comp_id=1       Team=Aston Villa
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=308&comp_id=1       Team=Blackburn
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=354&comp_id=1       Team=Bolton
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=536&comp_id=1       Team=Chelsea
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=942&comp_id=1       Team=Everton
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=1055&comp_id=1      Team=Fulham
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=1563&comp_id=1      Team=Liverpool
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=1718&comp_id=1      Team=Man City
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=1724&comp_id=1      Team=Man Utd
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=1823&comp_id=1      Team=Newcastle
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=1855&comp_id=1      Team=Norwich
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2093&comp_id=1      Team=QPR
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2477&comp_id=1      Team=Stoke
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2493&comp_id=1      Team=Sunderland
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2513&comp_id=1      Team=Swansea
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2590&comp_id=1      Team=Tottenham
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2744&comp_id=1      Team=West Brom
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2783&comp_id=1      Team=Wigan
URL=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=2848&comp_id=1      Team=Wolves
```

Comment: ok so i'm having a slight problem with this, when i try to run it, i get this error:    


Can't locate object method "find_all_links" via package "HTTP::Headers" at /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.14/lib/HTTP/Message.pm line 649.

any idea why?

Comment: all i need from this is the urls in a string array, can't seem to get it working, also getting this error: Can't locate object method "url_abs" via package "WWW::Mechanize" at solution.pl line 11.

Comment: I operated on the return value of `get`, which is the wrong class. Apologies. I edited with working code.